# Cannot select CollectionView item if the item integrates another CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uicollectionview, nscollectionview

My NSCollectionView item integrates another NSCollectionView. Everything works great but not when it comes to items selection in the first view.

When I set `collectionView1.isSelectable = true`, the `didSelectItemsAt` delegate is called only if I click somewhere else than the second (integrated) collectionView. To be clearer, if I click on a label, an image or a custom view: it works. As soon as I click on the second collection view, the delegate is not called.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Setting `collectionView2.isSelectable = true` to the second view.
   That did not work.
2. I followed [this tip](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/collection-view-default-gestures/). Curiously that did not work either. I got the same behaviour.
3. The only thing that works is to add a gesture recogniser on each integrated collection view. But this is so ugly...

I haven't tried on iOS yet with UICollectionView and cell selection, but I tend to think that the problem is the same.

**EDIT:**

[image]

So, if I click on the green label or everywhere on the blue part (which is the first collection view item), the `didSelectItemsAt` delegate is called correctly.
If I click on the orange NSView (with the second CollectionView inside), it's not called..

Heres is the simplified code of the first CollectionView:

```
class DashboardVC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: NSCollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initViews()
    }

    fileprivate func initViews() {        
        let flowLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 400.0, height: 380.0)
        flowLayout.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 20.0)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20.0
        self.collectionView1.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
        self.collectionView1.isSelectable = true
        self.collectionView1.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView1.delegate = self
    }
}

extension DashboardVC: NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let item = self.collectionView1.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CollectionViewItem else { return item }
        return collectionViewItem
    }
}

extension DashboardVC: NSCollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        print("I can't make this work!")
    }
}
```

And for the second collection view:

```
class TabularView: NSView {

    lazy var collectionView2: NSCollectionView = {
        let gridLayout = NSCollectionViewGridLayout()
        gridLayout.maximumNumberOfColumns = self.numberOfColums
        gridLayout.maximumNumberOfRows = self.numberOfRows

        let collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: .zero)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = gridLayout
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.isSelectable = true //-> does not work :(
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        return collectionView
    }()

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.addSubview(self.collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.topAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.leadingAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

extension TabularView: NSCollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfRows * self.numberOfColums
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "TabularCollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? TabularCollectionViewItem else { return item }
        return collectionViewItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i see your code for second collectionView??

Comment: @AnjaliShah I have just updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you're trying to disable selection on a specific item in `collectionView1` and instead have the user select the items of `collectionView2` embedded in this cell.

Take a look at `NSCollectionViewDelegate`'s `collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemsAt:)`

From the documentation:

> **Return Value**
>
> The set of NSIndexPath objects corresponding to the items that you want to be selected. If you do not want any items selected, return an empty set.

Comment: Not exactly. I just can't select any items on the collectionView1 if I click on their collectionView2. To select an item I need to click "around" the collectionView2. Maybe I should add a drawing to my post.

Comment: I understand that you want to click anywhere in a cell in `collectionView1`, even if the content of that cell is another collectionView, correct?
If that is the case, have you tried disabling selection on `collectionView2`?
Please update your question with the code you're trying to achieve this with and ideally a picture of what you're trying to display.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. I have updated my post with a drawing and some code. I tried to set the `isSelectable` bool to either true or false in collectionView2 with no success.